# Exporting many tables on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database

I would like to know, how to export many tables from oracle DB.

I use exp.exe, create file expdat.dmp and so on.
I choose to export only tables and there I must write which ones.

Is there any chance of getting all of them?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can export a list of tables, or you can export all tables owned by a specific user, or various other methods.  The exp command, with no args, will tell you this.  But it will not be all that clear -- it is usually easier to use a parm file to tell it what you want to export and how.

Comment: and how do I export tables by a specific user?

Comment: It has been a little while, so I am not 100% certain of syntax, but it is something like:
exp user/pass file=xxx.dmp user=(username1, username2)

Comment: thanks very much :) if this will not work, I've thought of another way which seems to work in small databases..

Comment: I forgot that you can also do exp ... tables=(table1, table2) and fromuser and touser stuff.  Exp has a lot of options -- two columns of them I believe -- so I would bet that it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a specified list of tables

```
 exp userid=scott/tiger file=dumfile.dmp log=logfile.txt tables=EMP,DEPT,SALGRADE consistent=y buffer=1024000
```

Answer (score 0):

If tables are more, instead of mentioning them in command line, you can input them in a param file and refer it in exp command.

```
exp userid=scott/tiger file=dumfile.dmp log=logfile.txt PARFILE=myexp.conf

$ vi myexp.conf
tables=EMP,DEPT,SALGRADE
grants=n
triggers=n
```